# How to check the value in 3rd layer in Firebase with angularfire2?

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I can check the values until the second layer, when it arrives in the 3rd where the array of objects comes I no longer can I wanted to print the value of the key "nomeOficina"

[Print db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6STKA.png)

[Print log of snapshot.value()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNi79.png)

Comment: get the key of the whole object then do a safe operator check like
`[key]?.[insideKey]?.nomeOficina`

Comment: I can not do this search for the snapshot already returned ??

Comment: You will have the base key for all the objects when you get them ? So you can use that

Comment: @Kai check my revised answer, it is a much better option.

Comment: I did it that way, thank you very much, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the nested value `nomeOficina` you need to enumerate `Oficinas` and each `childOfOficinas`.

The solution below assumes you just want to print each value of `nomeOficina` in the console (but to use this data you would probably want to push the whole object into an array to use it for something in your view).

I suggest using Firebase `forEach` (look at the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach)):

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('Oficinas');
    ref.once('value') // get the parent 'oficinas'
      .then((oficinas: DataSnapshot) => {
        oficinas.forEach((childOfOficinas: DataSnapshot) => { // use forEach to enumerate the children of oficinas
          childOfOficinas.forEach((child: DataSnapshot) => { // use forEach to enumerate each child of oficinas
            console.log(child.val().nomeOficina); // print the value nomeOficina
            return false; // you must return a boolean when you use forEach or the TypeScript compiler will throw an error, see Firebase docs for more on this
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
```

Note that if you are using TypeScript it is a good idea to get into the habit of adding the typings to the `DataSnapshot` values.